# JSON and Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I was looking at other posts about importing JSON into an angular application and I can't seem to get it to work. 
This is the format of the JSON.

```
    {
      "info": [
         {
          "name" : "test",
          "age" : 26
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is what I have in regard to my controller:

```
       var App = angular.module("App", []);
       App.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http){

         $scope.tests = [];

         $http.get('test.json')
            .then(function(res){
                $scope.tests = res.data;
         });

       });
```

And this is what I have in my HTML:

```
     <head>
       <title></title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="./javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
       <body ng-app="App">
         <div ng-controller="TestController">
            <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
               <h1 >{{test.name}}</h1>
               <h2 >{{test.age}}</h2>     
             </div>
         </div>
      </body>
```

When I open the html file in my browser the data does not render. Instead I get what is written in the curly braces.

Comment: Usually curly brackets means that there is are js errors and angular is not running. What does that error say?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=App&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: Its hard to make out the error from that...but here is a working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/xodoliqico/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you want `res.data.info`

Comment: Sorry it's a long error, but basically it says 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] and it directs me to angular.js:38 which contains function minErr(module, ErrorConstructor). Also if my data is much larger is there a way to import it without copying the data? Could I set a variable to equal $http.get('test.json')?

Comment: If you minified your controller, that will also cause problems because of dependency injection (you'll need to pass in an array containing string names of the injections, as well as arguments to the controller function, or use Angular's $inject service). Did you minify before you got the error, or are you getting the error regardless?

Comment: What do you mean by minify? @JoshBeam

Comment: Google it. It makes your code tiny for production. See http://jscompress.com/ for example.

Comment: Ok I've been using the minified version of angular the entire time. Just switched to the uncompressed version and now I'm getting this error "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load " @JoshBeam

Comment: @verygreen, the error isn't in the code you've supplied. It's in some other code somewhere else that we can't see. Can you provide the rest of your code please?

Comment: @JoshBeam this is all the code I've written. I've changed the names and my JSON data can't be posted here.

Comment: @verygreen, I'm referring to the rest of your HTML file, for instance. There's no `head` tag in the example you've given, so it would be helpful to see the entire HTML file to see if there's any errors with how you included your scripts.

Comment: @JoshBeam ok made the edit

Comment: @verygreen, `Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load` means the AJAX request failed. Are you running a server on your machine, or just opening your html file in the browser? `$http` sends an XMLHttpRequest (your AJAX) to retrieve `test.json`. Make sure the path to `test.json` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http.get makes an ajax call to the URL you specify. It should be hosted on a proper web server (node.js for example) . the way you have it, is not getting a response from test.json because it is not served properly.

Comment: I have the code of a server, but now I'm not getting any errors and nothing is displaying.

Comment: I recommend using Google chrome developer tools (f12) to see exactly what's going on. You can check the xhr tab to see what's coming from the server. If the json file is coming properly, the your problem is angular (client side)

Comment: Ok my json file is loading properly. What should I do about angular?

Comment: The next step for me would be do a console.log(res) after asign it to the $scope to see if res.data actually exists and has the information you need

Comment: Make sure that res.data actually exist.

Comment: Glad to help. Please rate the answer